# how to make custom field in WordPress user profile read only?

Tags: wordpress, plugins, advanced-custom-fields

In WordPress I want to adapt the custom field in user profile to be a read only field.

I have tried achieving this with the Advanced Access Manager plugin, but I was not able to hide the field.

[image]

Comment: These are not standard WP fields. I suggest you identify which plugin is adding them and ask the plugin author directly.

Comment: @Yogi Aditya Pratomo What did you tried already? You could consider to inject custom css / js to your admin page.

Comment: When you find the right filter, you can use the input tag readonly attribute https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_readonly.asp

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are only three filters hooks in the Edit User and Profile pages: user_contactmethods, admin_color_scheme_picker and show_password_fields. Everything else has to be done with jQuery. replace () your_lable with your lable

```
add_action('admin_init', 'user_profile_fields_disable');

function user_profile_fields_disable() {

    global $pagenow;

    // apply only to user profile or user edit pages
    if ($pagenow!=='profile.php' && $pagenow!=='user-edit.php') {
        return;
    }

    // do not change anything for the administrator
    if (current_user_can('administrator')) {
        return;
    }

    add_action( 'admin_footer', 'user_profile_fields_disable_js' );

}


/**
 * Disables selected fields in WP Admin user profile (profile.php, user-edit.php)
 */
function user_profile_fields_disable_js() {
?>
    <script>
        jQuery(document).ready( function($) {
            var fields_to_disable = ['your_lable', 'role'];
            for(i=0; i<fields_to_disable.length; i++) {
                if ( $('#'+ fields_to_disable[i]).length ) {
                    $('#'+ fields_to_disable[i]).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
<?php
}
```